# Is it possible to build RAID0 or RAID1 using 2 disk when one disk is not cleen?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, raid-1, raid-0

I'm using win 7.Is it possible to build RAID0 or RAID1 using 2 disk when one is not cleen?

I have 2 same hdd disks, one of them cleen and one with data.
I want to build RAID0 or RAID1 (on the fly) not cleaning the second disk is it possible?

Comment: Are you aware of what RAID-0 and -1 actually are? They are absolutely incomparable. Please pick one, then rephrase the question.

Comment: @DanielB yes, I understand what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and it's called software RAID.
Follow: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36504/how-to-create-a-software-raid-array-in-windows-7/
Under *nix machines learn about LVM.

Comment: I know about software raid but will it not flush my data on one of the disk?

Comment: No, it won't.
If you have, say 30gb free space on one of your disks, simply create raid with two partitions(each 30gb), one partition on your first disk, and second partition on another.

Comment: but I need to use all space, data from one disk must be rearranged somehow on two disk.

Comment: So you want to create a spanned volume. But you can't use whole second disk if you want to create stripped or mirrored volumes(aka read about RAID techniques)

Comment: no I don't want spanned volume, I want raid0, but not to loose my data, and not doing backup before creating it, so I want to create raid0 "on-the-fly" so data must be redistributed on two disks at creation time.

Comment: Oh, ok. It is supported i.e on intel:
http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020674.htm


raid migration:
http://download.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/irst_user_guide.pdf

Comment: So I need some intel disk controller? no software solution?

Comment: I suppose raid0 will work only as a hardware solution. You can also create mirrored volume/disk of your existing installation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938487.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this if your configuration allows the following.

Create a degraded RAID array with a the new drive and a drive missing, the unclean drive.  Boot and mount that degraded RAID array.  Copy over the files to the degraded RAID array from the unclean drive.  Then wipe it and add it to the array.  Viola, fresh new RAID array with old data intact!